# Office 365 "ForeignRealmIndexLogonInitialAuthUsingADFSFederatedToken"

Tags: cloud-computing, microsoft

I've detected a number of illegitimate logins to Office 365 (based on Client IP).  In the audit log, the operation is listed as "ForeignRealmIndexLogonInitialAuthUsingADFSFederatedToken."  I'm not terribly familiar with this logon type, and the MSDN articles didn't seem to provide the depth, only that it exists.  Can anyone explain what this could possibly mean?

Comment: Looks like SSO login from a domain that your main domain has a trust relationship with.

Comment: ADFS is federated active directory, that could be on-prem or in the cloud. Do you run Active Directory in Azure? have you set up any federated authentication?

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly horrible entry in the combined audit log and Microsoft certainly don't make it easy to decipher.

It appears to happen when a users device with an on-prem AD account sync'd to Azure AD tries to authenticate.

From what I can tell, the IP address should be related to the client device - which may itself not be on-prem at the time of authentication.

There are a couple of support articles related. As often the case with MS web support, they are fairly inpenetrable. [1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_security/foreignrealmindexlogoninitialauthusingadfsfederate/899032e6-99c3-493c-afda-b21df27e7a81), [2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/office-365-audit-log-search-understanding/85adcf63-4138-4360-8384-44fa6122e478)